# Is it offensive for a Christian to experience the Passover with a Jewish family?

Tags: gentiles, passover

Is it offensive for a Christian to experience the Passover with a Jewish family?

I am a Christian and would like to be able to experience the Passover in a genuinely Jewish traditional family, but I do not what to offend or worse be a source of scandal for the family involved.

Are we permitted to celebrate the Jewish Passover in a truly Jewish setting without offending your sacred religion?  Would asking for an invitation to a seder put the family in a bad position?

Comment: If need be, feel free to modify my question to make it acceptable to your community.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here.  Are you asking if it would be offensive for you to ask for an invitation to a family's seder?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, you have understood my thought correctly.

Comment: I started to write an answer and in searching for sources found [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27094/472).  That looks like a duplicate to me so I'm marking it as such.  If your question is different, please [edit] to clarify the distinction.  Thanks!